# Force an override of Content-Length in nginx

Tags: nginx

For an esoteric purpose, I want to override the `Content-Length` header for a given location.

I was able to add a `Content-Length`:

```
location ~ contentlength$ {
    add_header Content-Length 999 always;
    return 200;
}
```

This result in two `Content-Length` headers in the response though:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.13.9
< Date: Sat, 05 May 2018 06:46:28 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 999
```

How can I override the actual `Content-Length` instead of just tagging on another header?

(I'm aware this will break things - that's intended behavior in this test environment).

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for Nginx that can modify headers called ngx_headers_more: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#readme

You'll have to install the module manually (this involves recompiling nginx) or switch to openresty, a fork of nginx. Then you can use this directive:

```
more_set_headers "Content-Length: 999"
```